# Showing the names of checked checkboxes in the mail?

Tags: php, html

I have script in PHP and I want to show names of checked checkboxes, but values are used to calculate the sum.

**Code:**

```
$email = 'mail';    /
$subject = '';  
$message = '';  
$error = '';    
$charset = 'iso-8859-2';    


$head =
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=$charset\r\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$body = '';

$body .= "Sum: " . array_sum($_POST['product']) . "\n";

echo mail($email, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head) ? $message : $error;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="?" method="post" style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">


<input type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="2500" />Name1

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="3600" />Name2

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="6100" />Name3

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

And now, I need in email for example:

> Name2 - 3600
>
> Name3 - 6100
>
> Sum: 9700

but now i have only:

> Sum: 9700

How can I get this?

Please:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "2500" [1]=> string(4) "3600" [2]=> string(4) "6100" }

Comment: Can you var_dump $_POST['product'] and add it to your question.

Comment: `name="product[Name1]"` then just use the array keys

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="2500:Name1" />Name1
```

and extract the value and the name

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?" method="post" style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">
```